# "your account already has a valid certificate"error after resetting mac

Tags: ios

After resetting my mac,i am getting "your account already has a valid certificate".Couldnt able to create IPA file.

Answer (score 0):

Go Preferences > Accounts > Select Account > Details.
In the dropdown right click on iOS Distribution (or whatever is the name of your distribution certificate).
Export...
Set a password for the .p12 file.
Move and install this .p12 in the new mac.
Try Again.

Comment: Hi i am having only one mac.And i reset it.

Answer (score 0):

***i hope this will help you***

There's one more possibility  the old World Wide certificate expired and I guess everyone has already downloaded the new cert ([click here](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/)). However, you'll be seeing this error if you haven't remove the expired one. You may need to choose  View -> Show Expired Certificates to unhide expired certs. If the error is still there, try regenerate provisioning profile as advised by the others.